# UPDATE query by using python

Tags: python, mysql

```
def connect_to_db():
  mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host=CONFIG['host'],
     port = CONFIG['port'],
     user=CONFIG['username'],
     passwd=CONFIG['password'],
     database=CONFIG['database']
  )


   class MyTable:
      def __init__(self, conn, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.conn = conn
        self.cursor = conn.cursor()
        self.commit = conn.commit()

      def update(self, whereD, valueD): 
        if isinstance(whereD, tuple):
          where = "%s = '%s'" % whereD
        else:
          return "error"
        kv = ' , '.join(["%s = '%s'" % (k, v) for k, v in valueD.items()])
        sql = "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s " % (self.table_name, kv, where)
        print(sql)
        self.conn
        self.cursor
        (self.cursor).execute(sql)
        self.commit
```

and I tried to use this class like this:

```
mydb = connect_to_db()

tab = MyTable(connect_to_db(), "test")

tab.update(('name', 'aaa'), {'age': 800})
```

The original data is **name:aaa, age:20**

I connected to mysql by using aws. And I want to use UPDATE query by class MyTable. 
But it wasn't worked. Is there something wrong about my code?

Comment: Can you please post the value of ```mydb``` ?

Answer (score 0):

cur.execute("Update table set column= ? where cond= ?",[a,b])

You can try this code in update query

Thanks